# sprite image does not appear in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i being following this pygame tutorial and I can't have my sprite show on the window. When I run the program I see the rectangle move on the screen but it just shows all black. I try changing the background color on my rectangle according to the window but i still get nothing. I do notice that the rectangle changes shape according to the different images i try to load. Here is the code. Thank you

```
import pygame
import random
import os

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#SET ASSETS FOLDERS
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "img")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # sprite for the Player
    def __init__(self):
        # this line is required to properly create the sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # create a plain rectangle for the sprite image
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "p1_jump.png")).convert()


        # find the rectangle that encloses the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # center the sprite on the screen
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

    def update(self):
        # any code here will happen every time the game loop updates
        self.rect.x += 5
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = 0

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sprite Example")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
enter code herepygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've got the `pygame.display.flip()` statement at the end of the `# Game loop` written properly. It's got some garbage in from of it and isn't indented properly. When I fix those, your code start working properly (with my own test image anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your reply is greatly appreciated. Can you show me how you fix it please.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed one line near the end of the code in your question and it started working:

```
    .
    .
    .
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()  # <----- FIX THIS LINE

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for for taking the time to help me. I fix the last line and I still get the rectangle with no image in it. does it make a diference that I'm using python 3.5 or a mac computer?

Comment: heres what it looks like now.

Comment: # Draw / renderscreen.fill(GREEN)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()

Comment: That code looks OK as far as I can tell (although I cannot see the indentation). I'm using Python 3.7.0 on Windows, so that could be a possibility. It could also be the image you're trying to display so please upload it to something like [imgur](https://imgur.com) and then post a link to it in your question (or down here in a comment).

Comment: I tried with a different image and it worked. however, i'm curies as to why some work and others do not, if they all png files? #martineau

Comment: @marcelo: Without being able to actually download a copy of the problem image to examine, it's impossible for me to say what's wrong with using it—that's why I asked you to upload it somewhere. Perhaps the file got damaged and is corrupt.

Comment: /Users/marcelovilla/Desktop/pine-tree-png.html

Comment: this is one of many that I can't get to show on the screen, I appreciate any input . thank you I try and put the link of the one that works.

Comment: All that's needed is one that doesn't work, preferably the `p1_jump.png` file being used in the code in your question. I can't download a file that's on your computer, which is why I suggested first uploading it to the [imgur](https://imgur.com/) website and then providing an Internet link to it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/G7hEjGP (This one is the one on the code that it does not work. I notice the rectangle changes shape according to the image that i want to load, however the image it self does not appear. I downloaded the images that don't work from OPENGAMEART.COM the ones that don't work i got them last year and i don't member the website

Comment: They all work for me on my system, but they are comprised of different flavors of png. `anU9hmX.png` is an "indexed" image (one with a color table or palette) and both `stxFM6N.png` and `G7hEjGP.png` — those not working for you — are non-indexed full RGB images with transparency. Since I can't recreate the problem, there's little more I can do than give you that information. Perhaps knowing which kind work and don't will allow you to create replacement images in a compatible format. Also, I using pygame version 1.9.4.

Comment: Thank you for your help. after what you said i figure it might not be the code or the image. So i went and updated my pygame to the new version and reconfigure my IDE that i was using and sure enough went i ran the same code it worked.thanks again. #martineau

Comment: marcelo: Glad to hear that news and that my comments seemed to have helped you resolve the problem.